# Merging Three Tables common Column into One column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three Tables, Suppose

**Table1**

---

1. id
2. DDOCode
3. DesignationCode
4. Designation

**Table2**

---

1. id
2. DDOCode
3. DesignationCode
4. BPS
5. Designation

**Table3**

---

1. id
2. DDOCode
3. DesignationCode
4. BPS
5. Designation

This looks very strange that there are same fields in three tables, but there is a situation where i have to merge three tables into one , my main focus is on Designation and BPS, which i want to merge into one table either using a query or stored procedure, i can't apply left outer join , right outer join, neither inner join because i want all values from all three table, i think there would be a stored procedure which could solve my problem.

please assist me in such regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with either `union all` and `group by` or `full outer join`.  Because you have more than two tables, the `union all` is actually easier.  You are unclear on the final result, so this may be sufficient:

```
select id, DDOCode, DesignationCode, BPS, Designation
from ((select id, DDOCode, DesignationCode, NULL as BPS, Designation
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select id, DDOCode, DesignationCode, BPS, Designation
       from table2
      ) union all
      (select id, DDOCode, DesignationCode, NULL as BPS, Designation
       from table3
      )
     ) t123
```

For your refined problem:

```
select distinct DDOCode,DesignationCode, Designation
from ((select id, DDOCode, DesignationCode, NULL as BPS, Designation
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select id, DDOCode, DesignationCode, BPS, Designation
       from table2
      ) union all
      (select id, DDOCode, DesignationCode, NULL as BPS, Designation
       from table3
      )
     ) t123;
```

Comment: I also want to add a point that all values must be distinct and my final result is only three colums , i-e DDOCode,BPS, and Designation

Comment: @KhuramJan . . . Your comment is unclear.  Which values?  Is that before or after you bring the tables together?

Comment: I also want to add a point that all values must be distinct and my final result is only three colums , i-e DDOCode,BPS, and Designation

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION to merge all tables and not to loose any of rows and show them in a saperate view. If you want them in another table you can insert into, too.

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS(
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM TABLE2 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM TABLE3)
```